# Rails Dynamic Add nested Form Error not Show in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

Only First Appear in Parameters But Other That we Add Dynamically Not Show In Parameters

Application js

```
(function () {
    var ready;

    ready = function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.remove_fields', function (event) {
            $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1');
            $(this).closest('fieldset').hide();
            return event.preventDefault();
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.add_fields', function (event) {
            var regexp, time;
            time = new Date().getTime();
            regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
            $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
            $(document).find('.date-of-service').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });

            return event.preventDefault();
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(ready);

    $(document).on('page:load', ready);

}).call(this);
```

ApplicationHelper.rb

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, **args)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |ff|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: ff)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields" , data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

Our Form

```
<%= f.fields_for :lineitems do |ff| %>

  <%= render 'lineitem_fields', f: ff %>
```

Add another invoice line item'.html_safe, f, :lineitems%>

Partials We Add Dynamic

```
<%= f.fields_for :items do |ff| %>

  <%= render 'items_fields', f: ff %>
```

Add another item  item'.html_safe, f, :items%>

Comment: I would suggest looking at the HTML of the form, after you have (dynamically) added a field. Check what's different about the new field, compared to the others. It's not clear what the problem is, or how I can reproduce it, because your example is not minimal and is not complete (how are you using `link_to_add_fields`?). Moreover, as I say, you should start by looking at the generated HTML rather than all of this ruby code.

Comment: For the sake of other readers, I would also strongly recommend writing your question as a well-formed sentence, without unnecessary capitalisation. *"Only First Appear in Parameters But Other That we Add Dynamically Not Show In Parameters"* doesn't really make sense... I guess what you mean is: *"Dynamically added fields are not being sent along with other parameters, when submitting my form*"?

Comment: its working when i take item nested form  from _form partial and put it above my edithtml  above <%= render 'form' f: f%> it work but when i put it below it not work i want below

Comment: Dynamically added fields are not being sent along with other parameters, when submitting my form Yes

Comment: I'll say this once more: Look at the generated HTML. Look at the version that "works", and the version that "doesn't work". What's the difference? You still have not provided a complete code sample (Where is `<%= render 'form' ... %>`? How are you using `link_to_add_fields`?), so I don't know how to reproduce the problem. Once you find what's "wrong" with the HTML, only then look at how it's generated by the ruby/javascript code.